# What is the RESTful way of creating/updating multiple resources

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Using Spring MVC on the server, we have your basic REST API:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/entities")
public class EntityController
{

    //GET /entities
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody 
    public List<Entity> getEntities()
    ...

    //GET /entities/{id}
    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody 
    public Entity getEntity(@PathVariable Long id)
    ...

    //POST /entities
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody 
    public Entity createEntity(@RequestBody Entity entity) 
    ...

    //PUT /entities
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody 
    public Entity updateEntity(@RequestBody Entity entity)
    ...
}
```

This all works just fine. Now I'm wanting to be able to create or update mutliple `Entity`s with one request. My first thought was to add this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, consumes="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Entity> updateEntities(@RequestBody List<T> entities)
```

It would have the same URL as the `updateEntity` but handle lists (`[...]`). The `updateEntity` would handle a single object (`{...}`). However, on server startup I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'entityController' bean method public java.util.List<foo.bar.Entity> foo.bar.EntityController.updateEntities(java.util.List<foo.bar.Entity>) to {[/entities],methods=[PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'entityController' bean method public foo.bar.Entity foo.bar.EntityController.updateEntity(foo.bar.Entity) mapped.
```

So, from what I gather, Spring doesn't like two different methods with the same `@RequestMapping`, even though the `@RequestBody` is different.

This leads me to two questions. First, am I going about this the correct RESTful way? Am I in line with RESTful principles when I'm doing a PUT to the same URL and just allowing the request body to be a single object or a list? Would there be another correct way of doing this that Spring would like? (Ok, so the first question was actually three...)

The 2nd question is if there is something I can add to the `@RequestMapping` annotation that would differentiate the two methods enough, but keep the same REST API?

Thanks for any light you can shed on this.

Answer (score 0):

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) for each model

I have done on this way...with Two model: User and Tree

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/testBean", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json","application/xml"}, produces={"application/json","application/xml"}) 
    public @ResponseBody List<User> testBean(@RequestBody Object object) {
        System.out.println("testBean called");
        System.out.println(object.toString());

        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

        User user =mapper.convertValue(object, User.class);
        Tree tree =mapper.convertValue(object, Tree.class);

        System.out.println("User:"+user.toString());
        System.out.println("Tree:"+tree.toString());
        return userService.findAll();
    }
```